# arm64 starting February issue

Tags: ios, iphone, opentok, arm64, tokbox

Apple announced that is will not allow applications without arm64 to be uploaded.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

I have several questions:

1. Is it only about new applications?
2. Or existing applications on App Store (that don't support arm64)
   will be removed?
3. Or starting this date I will not be allowed to update existing application on App Store?

P.S. It's important for me, because I use tokbox sdk, and it doesn't support arm64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [slightly more detailed announcement](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b):

> As we announced in October, beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

So for *new* apps, the deadline is February 1, 2015. Existing apps may still submit 32-bit-only updates, but starting June 1, 2015 even existing apps must also support 64-bit when submitting updates.

Existing apps will most likely not be removed, not even after the June 1 deadline. But they will reject submitted updates if those do not contain 64-bit support. As far as I know, Apple has not removed any existing apps yet simply because they're "outdated".